# Rolling of two fair dice and its probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have the following scenario provided about the rolling of two dice.

[image]

The question I'm trying to answer states that:

Calculate the **probability of ($X_1$ − 1)+ > $X_2$**

I'm not too sure about the proper way of doing it, but I attempted something like:

$X_2$ = (1,2,3,4,5,6) representing 6 sides.

$X_1$ - 1 = (0,1,2,3,4,5)  for 6 sides too but since we are subtracting by 1, we have the following valid sides.

Therefore, the probability is **3/6 = 1/2** since sides 3,4,5 in $X_1$-1 is the only sides that is greater than some sides in $X_2$.

I'm not too sure if I'm doing it correctly, hence I would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: You have to count the pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x>y$, $x$ is a possible value of $X_1-1,$ and $y$ is a possible value of $X_2$

Comment: List all possible outcomes and compute $(X_1 - 1)_+ - X_2$. Maybe draw a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to consider numbers in pairs, that is count how many pairs of $(x,y)$ satisfies $(x-1)_+ > x_2$ then divide it by $36$.

We can  also use the law of total probability.

\begin{align}
P(\lfloor X_1-1 \rfloor_+ > X_2) &= P(X_1-1 > X_2)\\
&= \sum_{x_2=1}^6 P(X_1>X_2+1|X_2=x_2)P(X_2=x_2)\\
&=\frac16 \sum_{x_2=1}^6P(X_1 > x_2+1)\\
&=\frac16 \cdot \sum_{x_2=1}^4P(X_1>x_2+1)\\
&=\frac16 \sum_{x_2=1}^4 \frac{5-x_2}{6}\\
&= \frac16 \cdot \frac{1+2+3+4}{6}\\
&= \frac{10}{36}
\end{align}